How to get the job status and content of Azure Runbook in c#
I want to execute a runbook using webhook and want to retrieve the job status and output content in c# code. I can call the runbook and get job Id I am not able t get the job status and content. I tried using this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/get-runbook-content?view=rest-automation-2023-11-01&tabs=HTTP
but getting 401(Unauthorized error) . the document says pass clientid in header which I am not sure what to pass.

You don't need to pass any clientid in the request header to use Job - Get Runbook Content REST API. You need to pass a bearer token to authenticate it.
Authentication process contains 2 steps-

Register an application in Microsoft Entra ID and grant user_impersonation API permission to the app as shown below.



Grant Automation Contributor role to this app in the subscription level where you have created your automation account.

Navigate to subscription -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> select Automation Contributor role -> click Next.

Generate the bearer token as shown below-

Use this token while making the REST API call for authentication.

